# Why does a UITableView in a XIB in XCode 5 contain California city names?

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, cocoa-touch

When I create a Cocoa Touch Objective-C class, with or without a XIB, and then try to drag a `UITableView` onto the canvas I get a table view that is filled with California city names. I don't think this happened in earlier projects.  I want an empty table view. Where does this come from and how do I get rid of it?

Comment: It's an example of what will be populated there once you give it a data source.

Comment: Its just a sample data ..no need to worry!

Comment: Thanks! I understand.